# jQuery mouse drag event to add color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, onclicklistener

I'm new to coding and just created a Pixel Art Maker!

I am experimenting with jQuery and am wanting to know if:
• there is a proper event method that I can call to create an effect for: 
    "If I click and drag my mouse over certain cells, the colors of the cells will change."

Currently I have my table set up to where you click it once, it adds color, if you click it a second time, it removes the color.

I would like a user to just drag their mouse to give it the effect like they are drawing.

I tried implementing using mouseDown() and select() but that didnt work.

Any help on how I can implement this would be appreciated. Even better if you don't give me the exact answer right off the bat, but give me hints on what jQuery event methods and listeners I should be using and where I would put it in the code so that way I can learn.

Thanks all!

Codepen Demo: https://codepen.io/chaycesol/full/Qmmyjq

```
var height, width, color;
// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
$('#sizePicker').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  height = $('#inputHeight').val();
  width = $('#inputWeight').val();
  makeGrid(height, width);
});

function makeGrid(h,w) {
//Removes grid if one is already present before pressing submit  
$('tr').remove();

// Creating each table row
for (var i= 1; i <= h; i++) {
    $('#pixelCanvas').append('<tr id=table' + i + '></tr>');
    for (var j = 1; j <=w; j++) {
        $('#table' + i).append('<td></td>');
    }
}

//Draw with color in table cells
$('td').click(function addColor() {
    color = $('#colorPicker').val();

    if ($(this).attr('style')) {
        $(this).removeAttr('style')
    } else {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' + color);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/. Activate mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers **on mousedown** and deactivate on mouseup.

Comment: Thanks! Huge Help!